# PubSub in GCP Standard Environment (Python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am developing a python application in standard environment that requires publishing message to a Google PubSub Topic, which is further pushed to another endpoint. BUT I am unable to find PubSub in GAE Std. Env. What are the alternatives to this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pubsub is available on GAE std

examples:

- Python
  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-pubsub-samples-python/tree/master/appengine-push
- Java
  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-pubsub-samples-java/tree/master/appengine-push